# How to catch textchange event in textbox on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I'm developing a auto completor on mobile website. I want to catch textchange event of textbox on mobile. But I dont know how? Now I'm using focus, blur and setInterval to catch the change of textbox, but I think it's a bad idea for mobile website. Plz help me.

Cheers,
Bob khin

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: I dont think all of mobile support keyup event especially touch mobile such as iPhone, etc...

Comment: hi there, use this plugin: http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Comment: @Bobkhin `keydown` and `keyup` do work in ipod touch and from that I would gather that it works in ipad and iphone as well. Though `keydown` works pretty much the same as `keyup` ( `keydown` doesn't register while pressing, but triggers when releasing, just like `keyup`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not listening to the `change` event?

```
<input type="text" id="textbox"></input>

$("#textbox").change(function() {...} );
```

Comment: Hi Raminson, thanks for answer. I don't use .change event because the change event has same .blur event with other value in textbox.

Comment: Thanks so much. I use [isEventSupported](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/) to detect "onpropertychange" and "input" event. If the browser doesnt support, i'll bind "textchange" event plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I used this with no problem

```
<input id="textbox1" type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value)" />
```

Only tested on android though..but don't see why other mobile browsers should mis out on that.

Comment: Your mobile is qwerty keyboard mobile or touch mobile?